# RMQ pods on k8s not logging anything. don't see the logging folder on the pod

Tags: docker, kubernetes, logging, rabbitmq, devops

I have deployed RMQ statefulset with below rabbitmq.conf in configmap. log settings seems to be correct based below link. But some how I don't see the log folder getting created on the pod. Any suggestions on this one is greatly appreciated. Thanks

````
## Cluster formation
cluster_formation.peer_discovery_backend  = rabbit_peer_discovery_k8s
cluster_formation.k8s.service_name = rabbitmq
cluster_formation.k8s.host = kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local      
cluster_formation.k8s.address_type = hostname      
cluster_formation.node_cleanup.interval = 60      
cluster_formation.node_cleanup.only_log_warning = false
cluster_partition_handling = autoheal
queue_master_locator=min-masters

# Log settings
log.dir = /var/lib/rabbitmq
log.file = rabbit.log
log.file = true
log.file.level = info
log.file.rotation.date = $D23
log.file.rotation.count = 5
log.console = true
log.console.level = info
log.exchange = true
log.exchange.level = info

# rabbit
loopback_users = none
listeners.tcp.default = 5672
hipe_compile = false```

```rabbitmq@rabbitmq-0:/$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
overlay         100G   80G   21G  80% /
tmpfs            64M     0   64M   0% /dev
tmpfs            16G     0   16G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/nvme0n1p1  100G   80G   21G  80% /etc/hosts
shm              64M     0   64M   0% /dev/shm
/dev/nvme1n1    976M  389M  572M  41% /var/lib/rabbitmq/mnesia
tmpfs            16G   12K   16G   1% /run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount
tmpfs            16G     0   16G   0% /proc/acpi
tmpfs            16G     0   16G   0% /sys/firmware
rabbitmq@rabbitmq-0:/$ 
rabbitmq@rabbitmq-0:/$ 
rabbitmq@rabbitmq-0:/$ cd /var/lib/rabbitmq/
rabbitmq@rabbitmq-0:~$ pwd
/var/lib/rabbitmq
rabbitmq@rabbitmq-0:~$ ls
mnesia 
rabbitmq@rabbitmq-0:~$
````

Comment: - name: rabbitmq-data
          mountPath: "/var/lib/rabbitmq/mnesia"

This is my volumemount where persistent storage is attached

Comment: did you found log file in the kubernetes pod?@harishb

Comment: @Dolphin No . I haven't found the log file in rmq pod. taht is the puzzling part

```rabbitmq@rabbitmq-0:~$ pwd
/var/lib/rabbitmq
rabbitmq@rabbitmq-0:~$ ls
mnesia 
rabbitmq@rabbitmq-0:~$```